# How is js logical AND short-circuit evaluated?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I find this code from https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

```
(O.gaData = O.gaData || {}).expId && a.set(Nc, (O.gaData = O.gaData || {}).expId);
(O.gaData = O.gaData || {}).expVar && a.set(Oc, (O.gaData = O.gaData || {}).expVar);
```

With my common sense, the left part will be evaluated first and only if it's true, then the right part will be evaluated. So `O.gaData` will always be *ready* on the right part.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No you're not, that's just poorly written, confusing code.

Comment: @FizzyTea But it's GA on everyone's browser. Bytes === Money.

Comment: It must be correct then. :-)

Comment: Maybe the code was computer generated.